# Mean value with respect to maxwell's velocity distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, quantum-statistics

I don't understand why for an arbitrary $A$, the integral

$$ \int \text{d}^3v \;f(\vec{v})A(\vec{v}) $$

is the mean value $\langle A\rangle_f$ of $A$ with respect to Maxwell's velocity distribution. Would anyone be so kind and explain it to me please?

Comment: It's a weighted average. For a given velocity, the contribution to the average is weighted by the probability of particles having that velocity, which is given by the distribution function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the general definition of an average of a distribution. It is the generalization of the discrete case where the average is the sum (Probability of a result)$\times$ (the value of the result), i.e.

If the probability of getting outcome 1 is 1/3 and the probability of getting outcome 2 is 2/3 then the average would be
$$
\frac{1}{3}\times 1 + \frac{2}{3}\times 2 =\frac{5}{3}\, .
$$ 
You can see how, since the outcome $2$ is more probable, the average will be closer to $2$ than to $1$.  Of course if both outcomes have probability $1/2$ then the average is $\frac{3}{2}$.

When you go to the continuous case, the sum (Probability of a result)$\times$ (the value of the result) gets replaced by an integral (i.e. a continuous sum) so that
$$
\langle A\rangle = \int dA P(A) A
$$
where $P(x)$ is the probability density.  An example of this is the computation of the average position in quantum mechanics:
$$
\langle x\rangle = \int dx x P(x)\, ,
$$
where $P(x)=\psi^*(x)\psi(x)$ is the probability density.